# Java abstract class: protected fields or public set/get methods

Tags: java, oop

If I got an abstract class that I'm intended on creating sub classes from, is it better practice to have the fields in the abstract class to be protected or have the sub classes use setters and getters instead? Are there any pros and cons?

For instance:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    // option A
    protected int myProtectedInt;

    // option B
    private int myPrivateInt;
    public void setMyPrivateInt() {}
    public int getMyPrivateInt() {}
}

public class MySubClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: (1) I prefer the use of accessor  methods (option B) over direct field access.  This lets you control how the field is used entirely within that class file.  You may then expose access to the fields of interest to sub-classes via default or protected methods.  aka, encapsulation.  (2)  Review the "Principle of Least Privilege," and (3) as a general rule of thumb, start out private and change the access modifier when you discover you need it.  (Unless this code is meant to be extended by others that don't have access to the source, but I suspect you're not writing a black-box framework.)

Comment: For this question, I think it is more about encapsulation than polymorphism. It also depends on what you wanna do with the subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. You've pointed me in the right direction. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's in part subjective (depends on the scenario) and part preference. I personally never open the fields even to the children classes. Preferring private fields with protected (or public, as needed) getters and setters have helped me a great deal in the past. While it adds a few more characters to code, and makes the code look a little less intuitive, I can list a few pros of my preferred approach that may convince you to start using getters/setters with private fields:

1. Better control: The parent class knows exactly what changed and what was accessed. Instead of a child class (or grand child) directly modifying the fields, they have to use the setters, giving the parent class the visibility that might come handy some day
2. Better flexibility: the parent class has the flexibility to change how the fields are maintained, possibly calculated or even refactores significantly without imoacting any of the children classes as long as the signatures of the getter/setters are preserved.
3. Logging, data access and validations: the getter/setter methods can have programmatic logic to log or check for the data type or perform validations before or after the access or modification. You may be able to add business logic to ensure the caller has access to reading or writing to the fields.
4. Better description: methods can be documented better (JavaDocs of methods can be made much more explanatory than the same of the member variables)

Hope this helps.

Comment: In that case, do you mind approving my answer as 'answered'? :)